# Why does `has_many` association generate an error when using the `:dependent => :restrict`option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Ruby 2.2 , Rails 3.21

I got the following error when I try to destroy my object.
This happen with any object whose model has an association with `:dependent => :restrict` option

This error is strange because it suggests a NIL object, though when I log the class and Id of the related object just before the error, it shows the expected class with correct ID.

> NoMethodError in Projects::ProjClefsRepartitionController#destroy
>
> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
>
> app/controllers/projects/proj_clefs_repartition_controller.rb:322:in
>   block in destroy
>
> app/controllers/projects/proj_clefs_repartition_controller.rb:315:in destroy

This is the related code of the ProjClefsRepartitionController controller :

```
294# def destroy
295#
296#    messages = {}
297#
298#    # Create the @proj_clef_repartition objet
299#    unless creer_instance_objet_et_render_parent_si_impossible(ProjClefRepartition, params[:id], params[:proj_sous_projet_id], [{:proj_sous_projet => [:proj_charges, {:proj_projet => {:proj_mesure => :proj_paquet_mesures}}]}]) then
300#
301#      enregistrement_ok = false
302# 
303#      @objet_de_l_erreur = @proj_clef_repartition
304#      @proj_sous_projet = @proj_clef_repartition.proj_sous_projet
305#      @proj_projet = @proj_sous_projet.proj_projet
306#      @proj_mesure = @proj_projet.proj_mesure
307#      @proj_paquet_mesures = @proj_mesure.proj_paquet_mesures
308#      @hist_version_sous_projet = HistVersionSousProjet.where(:proj_sous_projet_id => @proj_sous_projet.id).order{version.desc}.limit(1)[0]
309#
310#      @proj_clefs_repartition = @proj_sous_projet.proj_clefs_repartition
311#      @proj_charges = @proj_sous_projet.proj_charges
312#      @total_charges =  BigDecimal.new('0', 18)
313#
314#      # =================== DEBUT DE LA TRANSACTION ===================
315#      ProjClefRepartition.transaction do
316#
317#
318#        if sauver_version(@proj_clef_repartition, messages, nil, 3, nil, true) then
319#
320#          logger.debug "#{@proj_clef_repartition.blank?}"
321#          logger.debug "#{@proj_clef_repartition.class} (#{@proj_clef_repartition.id})"
322#          if @proj_clef_repartition.destroy then
323#            ajouter_message(t('activerecord.successful.messages.deleted', :model => ProjClefRepartition.model_name.human), :success, messages)
324#            enregistrement_ok = true
325#          else
326#            ajouter_message(t('activerecord.warning.messages.deleted', :model => ProjClefRepartition.model_name.human), :alert, messages)
327#          end # proj_clef_repartition.destroy
328#
329#        end # sauver_version(@proj_clef_repartition, messages, nil, 3, nil, true) 
330#
331#
332#        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless enregistrement_ok
333#
334#      end # ProjClefRepartition.transaction
335#      # =================== FIN DE LA TRANSACTION ===================
336#
337#
338#      afficher_maintenant(messages)
339#
340#      render 'projects/proj_sous_projets/show'
341#
342#    end # creer_instance_objet_et_render_parent_si_impossible(ProjClefRepartition, params[:id], params[:proj_sous_projet_id])
343#
344#
345#  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => exception
346#
347#
348#
349#
350#
351#    @hist_sous_projet = @hist_version_sous_projet.hist_sous_projet
352#    ajouter_message(t('activerecord.warning.messages.invalid_db_statement'), :error, messages)
353#    ajouter_erreur_concernant_exception_statement_invalid(exception, @objet_de_l_erreur)
354#    afficher_maintenant(messages)
355#    render 'projects/proj_sous_projets/show'
356#
357#
358#  rescue ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError => exception
359#
360#
361#    @hist_sous_projet = @hist_version_sous_projet.hist_sous_projet
362#
363#    ajouter_message(t('activerecord.warning.messages.delete_restriction', :model => ProjClefRepartition.model_name.human), :error, messages)
364#    afficher_maintenant(messages)
365#    render 'projects/proj_sous_projets/show'
366#
367#  end # destroy
```

Following is an extract of the log that is related to the error.
You can see that the object is not blank and has a class with a valid ID.

It shows `false` for `@proj_clef_repartition.blank?` logging.
It shows `ProjClefRepartition (96)` for `@proj_clef_repartition.class` and `@proj_clef_repartition.id`

> QUITTING ||| historisation_nouvelle_version_avec_origine
>   (pub_modification_id = 2) ||| ===>
>   output_hash[:id_hist_origine_modification] = 1202    (0.4ms)  SELECT
>   COUNT(*) FROM "proj_charges" WHERE
>   "proj_charges"."proj_clef_repartition_id" = 96
>
> false
>
> ProjClefRepartition (96)
>
> (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
>
> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 298.9ms
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
>
>   app/controllers/projects/proj_clefs_repartition_controller.rb:322:in`
>   block in destroy'
>
> app/controllers/projects/proj_clefs_repartition_controller.rb:315:in
>   `destroy'
>
> Rendered
>   /home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rail3/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb
>   (2.4ms)   Rendered
>   /home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rail3/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb
>   (1.9ms)   Rendered
>   /home/douglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rail3/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb
>   within rescues/layout (21.8ms)

It does not make sense. I checked the full trace, and noticed that the "Nil" object error which happened in active_record has_many association.
Here it is the full trace :

---

> NoMethodError in Projects::ProjClefsRepartitionController#destroy
>
> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass Rails.root: /var/www/odpf
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> activerecord (3.2.21)
>   lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:58:in
>   `cached_counter_attribute_name'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21)
>   lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:54:in
>   `has_cached_counter?'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21)
>   lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:37:in
>   `count_records'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21)
>   lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:261:in `size'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21)
>   lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:280:in
>   `empty?'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21)
>   lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `empty?'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21)
>   lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_many.rb:63:in `block in
>   define_restrict_dependency_method'
>
> activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in
>   `_run__1417810521555210605__destroy__1154072583585286936__callbacks'
>
> activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `__run_callback'
>
> activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   `_run_destroy_callbacks'
>
> activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   `run_callbacks'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:254:in `destroy'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:254:in `block
>   in destroy'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block
>   in with_transaction_returning_status'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in
>   `transaction'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in
>   `transaction'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in
>   `with_transaction_returning_status'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:254:in
>   `destroy'
>
> app/controllers/projects/proj_clefs_repartition_controller.rb:322:in
>   `block in destroy'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in
>   `transaction'
>
> activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in
>   `transaction'
>
> app/controllers/projects/proj_clefs_repartition_controller.rb:315:in
>   `destroy'

So I checked my model ProjClefRepartition.

I made a successful test without error when I removed the `, :dependent => :restrict` part of the two line :

```
  has_many :proj_contributions, :dependent => :restrict
  has_many :proj_charges, :dependent => :restrict
```

---

```
require Rails.root.to_s + '/lib/opf_modules/opf_outils_models.rb'

class ProjClefRepartition < ActiveRecord::Base

  include OutilsModels

  # Renforcement de la sécurité avec declarative_authorization Gem
  using_access_control

  # Modifier les attributs contenant des string vides en des nil
  before_validation :blank_string_attributes_to_nil

  attr_accessible :code, :designation, :proj_sous_projet_id, :motivation, :pub_modification_id

  validates :code, :designation, :proj_sous_projet_id, :pub_modification_id, :admin_utilisateur_id, :presence => true

  attr_accessor :montant_contributions_total

  validates  :code, :length => { :in => 2..19 }, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  validates :designation, :length => { :in => 2..60 }
  validates :motivation, :length => { :in => 5..600 }, :allow_blank => true

  validate :clef_repartition_exclusive_a_un_unique_sous_projet

  belongs_to :proj_sous_projet
  belongs_to :pub_modification
  belongs_to :admin_utilisateur
  has_many :proj_contributions, :dependent => :restrict
  has_many :proj_charges, :dependent => :restrict
  has_many :hist_versions_clefs_repartition, :class_name => HistVersionClefRepartition

  # Méthode utilisée par la collection_select box
  def texte_pour_collection_select
    # Groupé les attributs afin d'améliorer la compréhension de l'utilisateur lors du choix par la select box
    self.code + ' - ' + self.designation
  end

# -------------------------------------------------------------
#  Validations speciale
# -------------------------------------------------------------
private

  def clef_repartition_exclusive_a_un_unique_sous_projet

    # Lors de la création d'une nouvelle clé de répartition, l'ID est nil, et il n'y a aucun risque que la clef soit déjà utilisée par une charge
    unless id.nil? then

      # Trouver toutes les charges utilisant cette clé de répartition
      proj_charges = ProjCharge.where(:proj_clef_repartition_id => id)

      proj_charges.each do |c|
        if c.proj_sous_projet_id != proj_sous_projet_id then
          errors.add(:proj_sous_projet_id, I18n.t('activemodel.warning.messages.reaffectation_impossible', :modele_enfant => I18n.t('projects.proj_charges.model'), :modele_parent => I18n.t('projects.proj_sous_projets.model'), :modele => I18n.t('projects.proj_clefs_repartition.model')))
          break
        end # c.proj_sous_projet_id != proj_sous_projet_id
      end # proj_charges.each

    end # id.nil?
  end # clef_repartition_exclusive_a_un_unique_sous_projet
end
```

So I'm really wondering if this could be a bug in Ruby on Rails version 3.21.

Any help is more than welcome.

=== EDIT ===

The two other associated models (proj_charge and proj_contribution) do have the following line :

```
belongs_to :proj_clef_repartition
```

Comment: Show your `belongs_to` part of the association.

Comment: I edited my question with this detail. The two associated models do have the following association `belongs_to :proj_clef_repartition`. I don't think it plays a role in this issue.

Comment: So you don't have `couter_cache` anywhere in your project? Well, then it definitely looks like bug in a framework.